# Installed Wine Applications Missing Icons

Tags: kubuntu, wine, icons

I'm not a newbie to Ubuntu or to WINE and have been using both for years, always on Ubuntu Studio, but on a fresh Kubuntu 22.10 installation on an old laptop, then an installation of WINE, the downloaded EXE of Notepad++ would not run even with `wine %s` as the `Open With`. Running the application's installer from the command line, it installed properly but the desktop application has no icon other than a blank rectangle unless I view the Desktop as a folder in the file manager where it shows the proper icon.

When I view the installed application's properties, it shows `Open With` as Kate which I understand is a text editor on this version of Ubuntu but the application still opens in WINE as it should.

The application itself runs fine under WINE and I use it on my other systems so I do not understand these odd issues although this is the first I've tried WINE 7. Before installing any other WINE applications, I would like to get these issues resolved so any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly like this answer because it apparently means that it will have to be done every time I install a Windows application but, unless someone has an actual fix, it seems to do the trick.

Run this in terminal:

`sudo update-desktop-database`